# App Launcher for X11 (Xpra)

Tags: software-recommendation, launcher, remote-desktop

After using tigervnc for a while, and enjoying the Unity launcher favorites on the side, I switched to Xpra for a more seamless desktop experience. Launcher functionality would be nice, so I made a folder with a bunch of files like

```
ln -s `which firefox` firefox
```

and then showed the directory in nautilus, but double clicking doesn't launch things. (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/437 or something similar I guess.)

Is there a GUI launcher (preferably in apt) that works with X11 forwarding and similar?

The ideal solution would be for me to have icons in my local Windows' start menu, with icon overlays to indicate their remote nature, but I'd be happy to settle for having an additional "task bar" on the screen.

**Edit:**

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

I installed thunar. While I'm happy to use Nautilus, hiding/showing parts of it is global. This is true for Thunar as well, but I can change it in thunar and use thunar only for this purpose.

I dragged the .desktop files I want from /usr/share/applictions to my Desktop and made sure they were executable. I double clicked them to "approve" them.

I launch `thunar ~/Desktop`, hid everything, resized the window to fit the icons I have and closed it. Then I installed xfce4-settings and ran xfce4-settings-editor. To the thunar channel I added "misc-remember-geometry" (see https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/hidden-settings) and set it to True.

Now when I start x2go in single command mode I just have it run `thunar ~/Desktop` and I have a remote launcher.

Comment: [x2go](https://wiki.x2go.org/)? Didn't you say [xpra](https://www.xpra.org/) in your question?

Comment: Ultimately I went with No machine. It's not free, but it also just works.